# Using MySQL, filter $_GET variables from HTTP['QUERY_STRING']

Tags: mysql, regex

A MySQL (5.5.8) table (named `usage_log`) stores thousands of PHP `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variables:

```
 id     | request_uri
--------|---------------------------------------------------------
 ...    | ...
 123456 | page_one.php?foo=123&bar=smtgh1&more=no&even_more=yes
 123457 | page_two.php
 123458 | page_twelve.php?get=123&a=letter
 ...    | ...
```

Using MySQL query, I want to filter names of `$_GET` variables from `request_uri` strings, to receive something like this:

```
 get_vars
--------------------------------
 ...
 foo, bar, more, even_more
 get, a
 ...
```

This definitely looks like a job for regexp but MySQL `regexp` function returns 0 or 1, so there's not much use of it, I guess. Is what I want even feasible in My SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly in MySQL but you could use [MySQL User-defined functions](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/). 
Hovever, I'd advise to do this transformation in PHP if possible.

Related/duplicate SO questions:

- [How to count words in MySQL / regular expression replacer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755408/mysql-regex-replace)
- [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)
- [How to Use Regexp in MySQL Replace Commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384796/how-to-use-regexp-in-mysql-replace-commands)

Comment: Thanks. This is useful. I can't vote your answer, but I will as soon as I can.