# How to update and replace string with random number using a regular expression in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, regex, wordpress

I'm trying to update a Wordpress table (wp_posts) that is using a URL with a two digit random number between 10 and 20 inside the URL to a new URL for a move to a new CDN. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://media13.oldcdn.com', 'http://newcdn.com');
```

That's fine and would (I believe) work well for what I want to accomplish except the number 13 in the example above could be any number between 10 and 20.

I think that I want something like this (but I am not savy in the ways of the database):

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://media REGEXP '\d\d' .oldcdn.com', 'http://newcdn.com');
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL supports wild cards in query strings in where clauses - e.g.

```
LIKE 'http://media__.oldcdn.com'
```

but not in `Replace` - you'll probably need a script for what you're trying to do. I found a solution here: [How to Use Regexp in MySQL Replace Commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384796/how-to-use-regexp-in-mysql-replace-commands)

Comment: Not stellar, but I think I have an idea of the logic you are thinking of suggesting... :)

Comment: Or plan B... how much data do you have? - could you rip it into CSV, process it as text and then upload?

Comment: hmmm... interesting idea. I may just try that! Thanks!

Comment: You could easily pull it into Textpad, etc. Gimme a shout if you need help with Regex